# How can I fit a regression line in a seaborn scatterplot of order 0 (constant)?

Tags: python, regression, seaborn, scatter-plot

I have a seaborn scatter plot with a metric for different groups accross releases. I would like to fit a constant line for each group to see how they perform in comparison to each other. I tried to use the seaborn.lmplot like this:

```
 seaborn.lmplot(x="release", y=metric, palette="PRGn", hue=hue, data=data, order=0)
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the minimum value for the parameter order is 1, therefore it fits a line of order 1 (y = ax + b) and not of order 0 (y = c). Is there a simple way to fit a constant line using seaborn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the axes that `lmplot` is plotting into, then use [`axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html) to plot a horizontal line. Use `sns.color_palette()` to get a list of colors that seaborn will use, then use the same colors in the `axhline` calls:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="smoker", data=tips, markers=["o", "x"])

current_palette = sns.color_palette()  # get colors that seaborn uses

ax = g.axes[0][0]

# draw horizontal lines making sure they are the same color as seaborn uses
for i in range(len(ax.lines)):
    ax.axhline(i + 3, c=current_palette[i])

plt.show()
```

[image]

From the comments, the solution in the end was to adapt the above example to the following:

```
g = sns.lmplot(x="release", y=variable, hue=hue, data=data, fit_reg=False)

current_palette = sns.color_palette()

medians = data.groupby([hue]).median()[variable].tolist()

for i in range(len(medians)):
    g.ax.axhline(medians[i], c=current_palette[i])
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, however, i have many groups, and i would like to keep the same palette, so i know which line correspond to which points, based on the parameters palette and hue.

Comment: @kabinja OK, I think I understand. I've updated my answer. See if that helps?

Comment: I used your idea and finally manage to achieve what i wanted. Basically i used the code below:     sns.set_palette("PRGn")
    g = sns.lmplot(x="release", y=variable, hue=hue, data=data, fit_reg=False)
    
    current_palette = sns.color_palette()

    medians = data.groupby([hue]).median()[variable].tolist()
    for i in range(len(medians)):
        g.ax.axhline(medians[i],  c=current_palette[i])    If you edit your answer so it does what i wanted to do i can accept it :)

Comment: @kabinja I've put the solution in my answer. I think it is different enough for you to write your own answer (if you wish) and I will remove the edit I just made. But it's up to you

Comment: No worries you did all the heavy lifting, thanks again